# How create an Enumerable with specific objects

Tags: ruby

I have class with enumerator.

How to limit the access only for 3 objects?

```
class My
 include Enumerable
 def initialize(*s)
  @s = s
 end
 def each(&blok)
  @s.each(&blok)
 end
end
```

this is ok, only string and integer and My

```
 b = Array.new(3)
 m = My.new
 my = MySuperObject("normal","slowly",1,m)
```

this not ok, double, array

```
 my = MySuperObject(1.5,"ok",b,m)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean like this?

```
require 'forwardable'
class MySuperObject
  extend Forwardable
  def_delegators :@target, *Enumerable.instance_methods
  def initialize(*args)
    if args.any? { |arg| ![String,Fixnum].include?(arg.class) }
       #alternatively as @tadman pointed out you could use
       #args.all? { |arg| arg.is_a?(String) || arg.is_a?(Fixnum) }  
       raise ArgumentError, 'Must be a String or Integer'
    else
       #what ever you need to do here
       @target = args
    end 
  end
end
```

then

```
MySuperObject.new(12,"String")
#=> #<MySuperObject:0x2c1e568>

MySuperObject.new(12.4,"String")
#ArgumentError: Must be a String or Integer
```

Do to your complaint about this not being an Enumerable class of which there is no such thing (Enumerable is a module included in some classes) I have updated my answer to delegate all enumerable methods to `@target`.

```
MySuperObject.instance_methods.sort - Object.methods
#=> [:all?, :any?, :chunk, :collect, :collect_concat, :count, :cycle, 
     :detect, :drop, :drop_while, :each_cons, :each_entry, 
     :each_slice, :each_with_index, :each_with_object, :entries, 
     :find, :find_all,:find_index, :first, :flat_map, :grep, 
     :group_by, :inject, :map, :max, :max_by, :member?, :min, 
     :min_by, :minmax, :minmax_by, :none?, :one?, :partition,:reduce, 
     :reject, :reverse_each, :select, :slice_before, :sort, :sort_by, 
     :take, :take_while, :to_a, :zip]
```

Please note rubyists love duck typing and constraining inputs like this should have a good reason for doing so as it breaks this concept.

Comment: You can also do `case (arg); when String, Fixnum` which often evaluates more quickly.

Comment: @tadman updated my answer as you are correct `is_a?` is more customary.

Comment: this is not working if  include Enumerable all objects is String ;-(

Comment: @user1415926535897 what do you mean? it works fine with `MySuperObject.new("String","String","sing a long")` maybe your question is unclear

Comment: this is not working if  include Enumerable all objects is String ;-(  .class get String not My

Comment: I'd like to second your objection to testing vs. classes so rigidly in the first place. A more Ruby implementation would be to require incoming objects to have a `.to_s` or `.to_i` method in order to be useful.

Comment: ok, what identyfing better than .class

Comment: @user1415926535897 you would have to explain your reasoning behind the constraint for that question to be answered like @tadman stated possibly checking to make sure it can respond to a given method like `arg.respond_to?(some_method)`

Comment: This class is NOT enumerator. no have .push .add etc

Comment: @user1415926535897 niether is yours you have simply included the Enumerable module which does nothing without implementation. Even so I have updated my answer. As a note `push` and `add` are not Enumerable methods either `push` is an `Array` method and `add` is nothing at all. If you would prefer array methods then change to `def_delegators :@target,*Array.instance_methods` but basically this is just an Array now and should probably be initialized as such

Comment: yes, this is good answer